# In the detail title bar, show “Picture X of Y”

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having issues on  1 out of 3 challenges.

1st challenge
 Use Interface Builder to select the text label inside your table view cell and adjust its font size to something larger – experiment and see what looks good. (Done)

2nd challenge 
In your main table view, show the image names in sorted order (Done)

The 3rd challenge is
 "Rather than show image names in the detail title bar, show “Picture X of Y”, where Y is the total number of images and X is the selected picture’s position in the array. Make sure you count from 1 rather than 0."

Im creating a simple table view row with cells, with  images and when you click on it it will show you the picture.

I have an idea but I'm struggling. So I know that the title will use string interpolation and I have already created

```
var selectedPictureNumber = 0
var totalPictures = 0
```

Now I have tried creating

```
var selectedPictureNumber =  pictures[indexPath.row]
                     or

var selectedPictureNumber = indexPath.row
```

But I get error messages

Heres what I got on mainViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

        var pictures = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Adds a title to the navegation bar.

        title = "Storm Viewer"


        //This makes the title larger as well.
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

        // THis code manages the images from the files saved locally to xcode

        let fm = FileManager.default
        let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
        let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)


        for item in items {
            if item.hasPrefix("nssl"){
                pictures.append(item)

            }
        }
        // This pictures.sort makes the arrays sort in order.

        pictures.sort()
        print(pictures)
    }

    // This code creates  the table view rows , adds the table cells and adds the pictures to each table view cell.


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pictures.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "picture", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = pictures[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController{
            vc.selectedImage = pictures[indexPath.row]
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Heres what I have on my detailViewController.swift

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    // Outlets

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    // Vars
    var selectedImage : String?
    var selectedPictureNumber = 0
    var totalPictures = 0

    override func viewDidLoad(){

        title = selectedImage

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // THis code makes the title of the navegation bar on the detailViewcontroller the name of the img.

        title = selectedImage


        // This line will make it so that the title on the navegation bar will not be large.

        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never

        //This code lets the images that are on the detailViewController

        if let imageToLoad = selectedImage{
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageToLoad)
        }

    }


    // This code will make the Navigation bar appear & Dissapear with a touch on the screen.

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = false
    }
    }
```

Comment: What do the errors say?

Comment: When I use the Indexpath.row I get "nstance member 'row' cannot be used on type 'IndexPath'. When I use pictures[indexPath.row] i get "Use of unresolved identifier 'pictures' "

Comment: Where were you trying to do this?

Comment: @DanielAlejandroMorelCespede seems that you are trying to do it outside the scope of `didSelect` and in the other case even outside the class that contains `pictures`. Check how you are passing the image to detailViewController and do the same with the number.

Answer (score 3):

I have got your question, just update your code in `mainViewController.swift` as follows:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController{
        vc.selectedImage = pictures[indexPath.row]
        vc.selectedPictureNumber = indexPath.row + 1
        vc.totalPictures = pictures.count
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

You have to add property of selectedPictureNumber and totalPictures to DetailViewController

```
   var selectedPictureNumber : Int?
   var totalPictures : Int?
```

Then in `detailViewController.swift` file, Inside `viewDidLoad` method add following code.

```
self.title = "Picture \(selectedPictureNumber!) of \(totalPictures!)"
```

To avoid warnings you need to add "!"

I hope this is solution which are you looking for.